# odd text inserted into duplicate question that was closed

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

I had the last close vote (duplicate) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966995/does-java-have-a-tool-like-reflector-closed). After I closed it, it contained this:

```
> **Possible Duplicates:**  
> [Reflector for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722378/reflector-for-java)  
> [](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718935/is-a-functional-language-a-good-choice-for-a-flight-simulator-how-about-lisp/722387#722387)  


does java have a tool like reflector?  i.e. to decompile the code

can java be just as easily decompiled as .net?
```

I'm assuming it contained only the bottom two lines and not the empty link before being closed and **not the link with no text.** The other peculiar thing is the id of the question that all five of us closed it as a duplicate of (722378) appears twice in the destination of the empty link at the end.

This obviously isn't a huge deal, but I thought I'd report this anyway. :D

Answer (score 6):

The first link links to question 7223**78**, the second one to answer 7223**87**. (You can submit an answer id as the duplicate id, that's not prevented on submit on the server. That's probably the real bug here.)

Comment: oh, interesting -- we accept answer ids? that's definitely a bug..

Comment: @Jeff was this bug fixed? I just tried to reproduce it for the fun of it and cannot

Comment: @Earlz: It still works if you are careful to not trigger the client-side verification. See the automatically inserted duplicate comment on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48299 , which links to an answer...

Answer (score 0):

We improved the close duplicate dialog quite a bit, and this bug was also fixed.

> [image]

1. Shows full preview of proposed duplicate in a scrollable `<div>`
2. No longer uses drop-down behavior but simpler "after pause in typing, attempt to load the question URL or ID you just entered in a preview below the input area"
3. You can click on the previously chosen duplicates below, to get an instant preview of the dupe to judge if it is actually a duplicate or not.
4. Handy search link in upper right (with improved search help page) to help you find those pesky dupes

Comment: 1) Jeff, is there a better question in which to discuss this change? 2) Discussion: please add a 1-pixel border around the scrolling div.